# Exploring Class Object Creation with the help Of gdb : C++

Tags: c++, gdb

Consider below code, I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>



using namespace std;

class employee{
int ID;
char* name;

        public:

employee(int id,const char* ptr);
~employee();
int getID();
char* getName();
};

employee::employee(int id,const char* ptr):ID(id){
        name= (char*) malloc((strlen(ptr)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(name,ptr);
        cout << "Employee with ID : " << ID << " Name : " << name << " constructed." << endl;
}

employee::~employee(){
        cout << "Employee with ID : " << ID << " Name : " << name << " destructed." << endl;
        free(name);
        name=NULL;
}

int employee::getID(){return ID;}
char* employee::getName(){return name;}


int main()
{
 employee Ob1(145645,"Edward Collins");
 cout << "Employee Details:" << endl;
 cout << "ID: " << Ob1.getID() << " Name : " << Ob1.getName() << endl;


return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall GDB.cpp -o GDB


$ ./GDB
Employee with ID : 145645 Name : Edward Collins constructed.
Employee Details:
ID: 145645 Name : Edward Collins
Employee with ID : 145645 Name : Edward Collins destructed.
```

Now I am trying to find out the addresses where `Ob1, Ob1.ID, Ob1.name, Ob1.getID(), Ob1.getName()` are stored:

```
$ gdb GDB
(gdb) break 39
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4012f5: file GDB.cpp, line 39.
(gdb) run


Breakpoint 1, main () at GDB.cpp:39
39       employee Ob1(145645,"Edward Collins");
(gdb) s
employee::employee (this=0x22abf8, id=145645, ptr=0x4020b8 <_data_start__+184> "Edward Collins") at GDB.cpp:21
21      employee::employee(int id,const char* ptr):ID(id){
(gdb)
```

I can see `this` pointer as `0x22abf8` i.e. at location `0x22abf8` Ob1 is being created.
I have tried as below:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at GDB.cpp:39
39       employee Ob1(145645,"Edward Collins");
(gdb) s
employee::employee (this=0x22abf8, id=145645, ptr=0x4020b8 <_data_start__+184> "Edward Collins") at GDB.cpp:21
21      employee::employee(int id,const char* ptr):ID(id){
(gdb) s
22              name= (char*) malloc((strlen(ptr)+1)*sizeof(char));
(gdb) s
23              strcpy(name,ptr);
(gdb) s
24              cout << "Employee with ID : " << ID << " Name : " << name << " constructed." << endl;
(gdb) print &ID
$1 = (int *) 0x22abf8
(gdb) x/d 0x22abf8
0x22abf8:       145645
(gdb) print &name
$2 = (char **) 0x22abfc
(gdb) x/d 0x22abfc
0x22abfc:       537103464
(gdb) info locals
No locals.
(gdb)
```

So basically I can see the address of `ID`; but I want to find out all the addresses of class members for constructed object and want to explore `how an class object is being constructed inside memory` i.e. addresses `Ob1,Ob1.ID, Ob1.name, Ob1.getID(), Ob1.getName()` with the help of gdb.

Can any1 help?

Comment: Why do you want to look at *addresses* of these things?

Comment: To show *values* of class members, try `print *this`.